# Putting custom View into ScrollView (Or HorizontalScrollView) programmatically (No Scrolling)

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

I'm struggeling to put a self-made view (size 3000px * 750 px) into any scrollView programmatically.

Information to my custom view: It simply extends View and there are just some drawing in OnDraw(), nothing special.

In order to gather all information for the drawing, this CustomView should be added, once a AsyncTask has loaded all information.

My problem is, that when I added my view programmatically to any ViewGroup containing a ScrollView or HorizontalScrollview, there is no Scrolling.

I've tried several layouts, for example this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutScroll">

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And once the AsynTask is finished:

```
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linLayoutScroll);
    linLayout.addView(new MyChartView(getActivity(), chartBuilder, ChartBuilder.DATASET.SPEED));*/
```

I tried to add my view to the LinearLayout, but often my View does not appear on screen at all or there is no scroling option and my view gets cut off at the end of display.

I guess there must be some magic trick to tell the scrollView to recheck its content and to decide whether there has to be a scrolling option or not. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was inside my customView. I didn't set the Width and Height of my view (setWidth(), setHeight()). So the view did not know how big it really is. :-(

Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: is there any way to get any hint when custom view comes in view port either it is in scrollview or not